# unit testing: send parameters to endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

my question is how to send parameter to my endpoint.

test

```
public function test_upgrade()
    {
       
        
        $billingChange3 = factory(Plan::class)->create([
            'user_id' => 1,
            'previous_price' => 150,
            'current_price' => 100,
        ]);
       
        $url = route(
            'users.filters'
        );
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->admin)->getJson($url,['search'=>'upgrade']);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        //till here correct 
        //but here it should return 2 since I have upgrade count 2  as correct it gives error
my api response is wrapped within data, so i have used data below
        $response->assertJsonCount(2,'data');
    }
```

my seach keyword can be any thing such as upgrade,downgrade`etc.  upgrade is when`current_price>previous_price``` and I have logic for that in controller

My vue dev tool shows url as below:
first:`"https://localhost:800/users/plan?filter=upgrade&page=1"`
In test I have passed params as getJson($url,['search'=>'upgrade']
Is that the correct way to pass paramters?

Answer (score 1):

Not correct. See function signature - you pass headers:

```
    public function getJson($uri, array $headers = [])
    {
        return $this->json('GET', $uri, [], $headers);
    }
```

Correct way:

```
$response = $this
    ->actingAs($this->admin)
    ->getJson(route('users.filters', ['search'=>'upgrade']));
```

Comment: thanks but I am not sure why I am getting just one response instead of two while doing         dd($response->getContent());

Comment: This depend to your controller logic - I not know how it works :) your question is about url generation in tests.

Comment: You send 'search' field, not upgrade. if($request->input('search') === 'upgrade')